# How to deploy a Java web aplication on OpenShift or Git?

Tags: java, git, openshift

I have created a web site using NetBeans IDE by File -> New Project -> Java Web -> Web Aplication using apache-tomcat-7.0.67 as my Server.

The website consits of 3 .jsp pages, 1 servlet and 1 javaBean and json.org (extension is .jar)

[image: example]

Now I'm trying to deply it on http://app1-lolcheck.rhcloud.com/ but I have no idea how both to use git or Openshift.

I've installed git, ruby and OpenShift rhc Client Tools.

Finally I have already done what this video says (but using Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbvOQ2gopwo

So what should I do?

Comment: Victor, I am a little confused. I watched the video. If you cloned the project and then pushed git push as the video shows, you have already deployed it. Could you please elaborate on what your expectation is so that we can help you further?

Comment: The way I understood it is that the video shows you how to create a new project. But I don't know how to upload an existing one.

Comment: Ok, I can help you partly to get started. Have you created an application using rhc command line or in openshift website? In other words, I know that you have the project on your computer, but you need a online application created so that you can deploy your project to said app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor,

I will try my best to answer your question in the general steps needed rather than the exact steps which will require some configuration.
If you log into your OpenShiftAcount and go into your developer portal you can go into your applications settings. Among other things, listed there will be git address.
What you will need to do is, assuming you have downloaded git, set it up following these steps:
[Getting started with git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)
Then you need to go into your project directory and initialize the git there using:

```
git init
```

then add everything in your project folder except what's included in .gitignore (more details on the link that i provided you)

```
git add .
```

then commit everything

```
git commit -m "Some commitment message here."
```

now you need to add the application git address to your git's origin

```
git remote add origin [git address like git@github.com:user/gitname.git]
```

then you deploy using

```
git push origin
```

There are a lot of things I did quick and dirty and the actual configuration of the projects for rhc will need to be done by changing some settings file or in some cases procfiles. With everything that you need to get used to, please use this as a guideline for solving your problem.

A good crash course on git is going to be very helpful in any development work with version control and especially so with web development since so much deployment is done using git.

I am by no means a git expert, not even close to it, but I do use it in android development, web development and recently even in arduino programs just becasue of version controlling it offers.

To remove existing remote origin

```
git remote rm origin
```

Then you can add it one more time using the git remote add I mentioned above.

Comment: When trying to do git commit -m "Some commitment message here." it says: "fatal: empty ident name for ... not allowed"

Comment: Try to avoid special characters in the comment. What was your comment?

Comment: doing git config --global user.mail "my_mail" and user.name "random name" solves the problem. However I have no idea where to find my git's application address.

Comment: If you go to openshift.redhat.com, log in to web console, click your application then look for source in the top right area, you will find something matching ssh://56a9886d0c1e66d7f300009c@app1-lolcheck.rhcloud.com/ /~/git/python.git/ that is what you need to set the git remote origin to.

Comment: Got the following errors I think remote origin already exist is because I've already tried doing what you said several times : http://imgur.com/a/Y6F89

Comment: The origin already exists. Just in case try git remote remove origin and then do the git remote add origin .... command again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103249/discussion-between-khanal-and-victor-andres-escudero).

Answer (score 1):

Git and OpenShift are two different things. Git is a version control software, like CVS or SVN. OpenShift is a PaaS provider, like Google App Engine. OpenShift is using Git to manage the deployment.

Your link shows that you've successfully created and deployed a running web app. The next thing you want to do is clone the source from OpenShift to your local disk, make changes and do a git commit and push your changes to the OpenShift cartridge. Your cartridge already has scripts that will be automatically be triggered to deploy your changes.

Comment: A problem I have with this aproach is that the proyects are structured different as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/BlcPsPJ.png. Do I have to just delete -> copy new files ->send them (is this commiting?)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Clone the source first into your local disk. Once you have done that, you can change the structure to however your project requirement needs. But at the same time, you would need to have the OpenShift directories (i.e. webapps) there as well.

Committing is saving changes to your local Git repo. Doing a git push will save your changes to the remote server which in this case is hosted in your OpenShift cartridge, and they will take care of the deployment too.

Comment: I can see you are using ant build tool for your project. You need to "mavenize" it.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:
Netbeans > Team > Git > Clone:
Give your Repository URL. something like ssh://app1-lolcheck.rhcloud.com/~/git/.... (Hint copy it from your application page on openshift...see on right side under "source code")
username will be automatically filled
provide private/public key (you can get from settings menu on openshift website)
select master branch and in next step give parent directory where you want to clone and finish. Now copy your project contents in that directory...
right click on project in netbeans, click git > Commit
Then right click again your project > Git > Remote > Push. Done
Application will be deployed within few minutes.

Comment: it says Incorrect credentials for repository at ssh://... I have a problem with the private/public key it looks like it asks for the file containing the key rather than the key. The key should look something like 84h87fug..bf83878?

Other steps went right when I copied my repository URL username automaticaly filled and then I clicked on Private/Public key.

Comment: Key is a file, so should select a key file (probably id_rsa) that you should have downloaded while setting up your first app.